# Branching Process: generation survival or extinction?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $p\in [0,1]$, and consider a branching process where the
>   number of offspring of an individual is zero with probability
>   $p$, and is two with probability $1-p$. Initially there is one
>   individual.
>
> a) For what values of $p$ will the branching process become extinct
>   after finite number of generations with probability 1?
>
> b) For the case $p=1/4$, calculate the probability that the branching
>   process survive forever.

**Attempt:**

Part a). Let me first compute the expected value of each generation. This would be $\mu=0*p+2(1-p)=2(1-p)$. For complete extinction, we need $\mu\leq1$. Using this requirement, we solve for $p$ to be inside $[0.5, 1]$.

Part b). let $x$=probability of complete extinction. Since we start with 1 individual, then $x=1*p+x^2(1-p)$. Since $p=1/4$, $x=1/3$.

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commnity wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Math1000 pointed out in a comment, your answers are correct.